# Radio item in TMainMenu not using dots but checkmarks

Tags: delphi, menu, c++builder, menuitem, c++builder-2010

Using standard VCL. If menu item in `TMainMenu` has `RadioItem` and a `GroupItem` is assigned, normally, it uses a **dot** to indicate the `Checked` property - one of the radioitems is checked and that is indicated by a **dot**. `RadioItem` property switches from checkmark to dots. This is how I want it to behave.

[image: Standard menu with dot as radio indicator]

However, if I assign `TImageList` to the `TMainMenu`, the **dot** becomes a **checkmark** instead even though `RadioItem` property is set to `true`.

[image: Checkmark if TImageList is used]

This seems like a bug in Delphi/C++ Builder, but maybe there is something I missed. As long as the image list is not assigned to the menu, the checkmarks are shown as dots instead.

Is there a way to assign image list to main menu but still have radio items behave like radio items (have dot, instead of checkmark)?

Also, if it is a bug, is it fixed in subsequent Delphi/C++ Builder versions (I am using the RAD Studio 2010)?

I am not looking for workarounds like "assign your own dot image", or "use third party main menu component". Only standard VCL components. The reason why is because third party components usually don't care for accessibility (support for screen readers) and I need support for that.

Unrelated to the question, when HighDPI is used the checkmark is stretch drawn from a smaller image with jagged lines, indicating it is an enlarged bitmap. However, the dot remains smooth. So clearly some difference in drawing there.

[image: Jagged edges of the checkmark]

Example code:

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
TMainMenu *mm;
TImageList *il;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
struct
    {
    TComponent* operator()(TComponent* fOwner, const UnicodeString &fCaption, const UnicodeString &fName, bool fDefault, bool fRadioItem, int fImgIndex, int fGroupIndex, bool fChecked)
        {
        TMenuItem* mi  = new TMenuItem(fOwner);
        mi->Name       = fName;
        mi->Caption    = fCaption;
        mi->Default    = fDefault;
        mi->RadioItem  = fRadioItem;
        mi->ImageIndex = fImgIndex;
        mi->GroupIndex = fGroupIndex;
        mi->Checked    = fChecked;

        if (fOwner->InheritsFrom(__classid(TMainMenu)))
            {
            static_cast<TMainMenu*>(fOwner)->Items->Add(mi);
            }
        else if (fOwner->InheritsFrom(__classid(TMenuItem)))
            {
            static_cast<TMenuItem*>(fOwner)->Add(mi);
            }

        return mi;
        }
    } AddMenuItem;

TComponent* own;
mm = new TMainMenu(this);
il = new TImageList(this);

own = AddMenuItem(mm, "File", "mmFile", 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
      AddMenuItem(own, "Radio 1",  "mmFileRadio1", 0, 1, -1, 1, 1);
      AddMenuItem(own, "Radio 2",  "mmFileRadio2", 0, 1, -1, 1, 0);

//mm->Images = il;      // Comment this line = dot, uncomment this line = checkmark
}
```

Comment: Assigning an ImageList makes the menu be owner drawn, and at least in older versions, the VCL's drawing code does not take radio items into account, a menu item is drawn either checked or unchecked when you don't apply your own image. I won't be able to check until tomorrow how newer versions behave

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with XE2. For a main menu with an assigned image list; If a radio item with an image is selected the image is drawn recessed. If a radio item without an image is selected, a radio is drawn.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Then it might do under-the-hood replacing of the system radio dot with a custom image. I've noticed it stretch-draws the ugly bitmap image of the checkmark (if high DPI is used), so could be what Remy Lebeau is describing that it becomes ownerdraw. I'll add some screenshots in my original post to illustrate that.

Comment: In the case of radio dots, the OS is drawing those, not the VCL at all, so it makes sense that the OS would use high-DPI images when needed. In the case of checkmarks, the VCL *may or may not* be drawing those (it does owner-draw recessed images), and the VCL in D2010 does not support High-DPI at all, so it makes sense that images get stretched in that case.

Comment: @Coder - Ultimately the VCL calls (when themes are on) DrawThemeBackground with part id 11 (MENU_POPUPCHECK).

Comment: *"Also, if it is a bug, is it fixed in subsequent Delphi/C++ Builder versions (I am using the RAD Studio 2010)?"* - If there were an mcve in the question, I could have tried in Seattle.

Comment: @GolezTrol C++ example added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody is answering, I am answering my own question. If anyone has a better reply, feel free to add and I will gladly mark it as a reply.

Basically I solved the problem by not assigning `TImageList` to the main menu, which avoids the problem and draws radio items with the circle. If there is a need to add images later, I'll have to look for other solutions, but for now this works.

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me too. When using images, it uses custom drawing instead of the windows system. And this poses a whole new pool of unexpected behavior. Especially weh using older delphi releases. Same happens when you use VCL styles.